# javascript Date

Tags: javascript

I have this code

```
function myFunction(){
    alert( new Date(getAllTime(2012,12,24)).toString());
}
function getAllTime(y,m,d){
    return getDaysMilisec(getDaysFromYear(y))+getDaysMilisec(getDaysFromMonth(m,y))+getDaysMilisec(d);
}
function getDaysMilisec(d){
    return d*24*60*60*1000;
}
function getDaysFromYear(y){
    return (bisect(y) ? 366 : 365);
}
function bisect(y){ 
    if( (y%4==0 && y%100!=0) || (y%400==0)) return true;
    return false;
}
function getDaysFromMonth(m,y){ 
    if(m==2 && bisect(y)) return 28; 
    if(m==2 && !bisect(y))return 27; 
    if(m==1||m==3||m==5||m==7||m==8||m==10||m==12) return 31; 
    return 30;
}
```

Whay the myFunction() print

> Fri Feb 26 1971 02:00:00 GMT+0200 (GTB Standard Time)?

Whay is not 24.12.2012?

Comment: why `20.12.2012` and not `24.12.2012` ?

Comment: how that fucntions linked? which function return *Fri Feb 26 1971 02:00:00 GMT+0200 (GTB Standard Time)* ?

Comment: What's wrong with `alert(new Date(2012,11,24))`?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Date.prototype.toString` method returns exactly that format. JS is behaving as expected. If you want the date returned in the format you're after:

```
var someDate = newDate();
console.log(d.getDate() + '.' + (d.getMonth()+1) + '.' + d.getFullYear());
```

JavaScript's Date object is a bit confusing, at first (well, it'll always be confusing to some extent IMO). But [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) can clear up a lot of things quite quickly

Answer (score 0):

Your `new Date(X).toString()` will return the date that comes X milliseconds after from 01/01/1970.

Your other functions return incorrect values because they never take into account the actual date (eg. `getDaysFromYear(y)` is only the number of days in a year and has nothing to do with the number of years since 1971).